# Getting the date from PHP's date() function

Tags: php, date

How can I use PHP's `date()` function to get the next day's date? I can easily get the current day's date. For example, if today is July 14, I would like to get July 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date('j F', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
date('y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strtotime function

```
strtotime("+1 day"); // will give u the next day
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on date:

date(' ... your format ... ', time() + 60 * 60 * 24); // **WRONG**; see edit for proof

then you have a timestamp of tomorrow which you can turn into a formatted date.

**EDIT**:

regarding the critics for adding (60*60*24).

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4*365; $i++)
{
   $t = time() + $i*60*60*24;

  if(strtotime("+1 day", $t) != ( $t + (60*60*24) ) )
  {
    echo "x: ".$t,PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

shows that indeed it's not sufficient to just add 60*60*24:

```
x: 1319882214
x: 1332583014
x: 1351331814
x: 1364637414
x: 1382781414
x: 1396087014
x: 1414231014
x: 1427536614
```

Comment: That won't work. Not all days are 86400 (60*60*24) seconds long :)

Comment: what? I beg to differ ... ;) ... I'd love to see +an example.

Comment: Some days are long 23 hours, others are 25 hours. Because of DST :)

Comment: What is the timezone of your environment? (date_default_timezone_get())

Comment: I had a bug in my code and in the updated post you'll find some timestamps that indeed proove me wrong ... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$timestamp = time();
$tomorrow = date("j F", $timestamp+3600*24);

?>
```

Comment: Same thing I said to Raffael1984: not all days are 86400 seconds long :)